# Detecting playing video inside of a WKWebView component

Tags: ios, iphone, webkit, wkwebview

With a WKWebView component and iOS 8, is possible to know if the user has clicked in an embedded video and it has started to play?

Comment: Hi Sobrino, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible :(( Sorry

Comment: I figured this way (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40185128/3164091) it works well on iOS 10.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this solution from Paulo Fierro.](https://paulofierro.com/blog/2015/10/12/listening-for-video-playback-within-a-wkwebview)