# How to detect a movie being played in a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'd like to know wether it's possible to detect a movie being played in the WKWebView?

Additionally I'd like to know the exact URL of the opened stream?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the solution(s) to this question required a lot of research and different approaches, I'd like to document it here for others to follow my thoughts. *If you're just interested in the final solution, look for some fancy headings.*

The app I started with, was pretty simple. It's a Single-View Application that imports `WebKit` and opens a `WKWebView` with some `NSURL`:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://tinas-burger.tumblr.com/post/133991473113")!)
        webView.loadRequest(request) 
    }
}
```

> The URL includes a video that is (kind of) protected by JavaScript. *I really haven't seen the video yet, it was just the first I discovered.* Remember to add `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to your `Info.plist` or you will see a blank page.

### WKNavigationDelegate

The `WKNavigationDelegate` won't notify you about a video being played. So setting `webView.navigationDelegate = self` and implementing the protocol won't bring you the desired results.

### NSNotificationCenter

I assumed that there must be an event like `SomeVideoPlayerDidOpen`. Unfortunately there wasn't any, but it might have a `SomeViewDidOpen` event, so I started inspecting the view hierarchy:

```
UIWindow
    UIWindow
        WKWebView
            WKScrollView
            ...
        ...
UIWindow
    UIWindow
        UIView
            AVPlayerView
        UITransitionView
            UIView
                UIView
                    UIView
                        ...
                    UIView
                        ...
                    AVTouchIgnoringView
                        ...
```

As expected there will be an additional `UIWindow` added which *might* have an event and hell yes it does have!

I extended `viewDidAppear:` by adding a new observer:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "windowDidBecomeVisible:", name: UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification, object: nil)
```

And added the corresponding method:

```
func windowDidBecomeVisible(notification: NSNotification) {
    for mainWindow in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
        for mainWindowSubview in mainWindow.subviews {
            // this will print:
            // 1: `WKWebView` + `[WKScrollView]`
            // 2: `UIView` + `[]`
            print("\(mainWindowSubview) \(mainWindowSubview.subviews)")
}
```

As expected it returns the view hierarchy as we inspected earlier. But unfortunately it seems like the `AVPlayerView` will be created later.

If you trust your application that the only `UIWindow` it'll open is the media player, you're finished at this point. But this solution wouldn't let me sleep at night, so let's go deeper...

### Injecting An Event

We need to get notified about the `AVPlayerView` being added to this nameless `UIView`. It seems pretty obvious that `AVPlayerView` must be a subclass of `UIView` but since it's not officially documented by Apple I checked the [iOS Runtime Headers for `AVPlayerView`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/AVPlayerView.h) and it definitely *is* a `UIView`.

Now that we know that `AVPlayerView` is a subclass of `UIView` it will probably added to the nameless `UIView` by calling `addSubview:`. So we'd have to get notified about a view that was added. Unfortunately `UIView` doesn't provide an event for this to be observed. But it *does* call a method called `didAddSubview:` which could be very handy.

So let's check wether a `AVPlayerView` will be added somewhere in our application and send a notification:

```
let originalDidAddSubviewMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, "didAddSubview:")
let originalDidAddSubviewImplementation = method_getImplementation(originalDidAddSubviewMethod)

typealias DidAddSubviewCFunction = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector, UIView) -> Void
let castedOriginalDidAddSubviewImplementation = unsafeBitCast(originalDidAddSubviewImplementation, DidAddSubviewCFunction.self)

let newDidAddSubviewImplementationBlock: @convention(block) (AnyObject!, UIView) -> Void = { (view: AnyObject!, subview: UIView) -> Void in
    castedOriginalDidAddSubviewImplementation(view, "didAddsubview:", subview)

    if object_getClass(view).description() == "AVPlayerView" {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PlayerWillOpen", object: nil)
    }
}

let newDidAddSubviewImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(newDidAddSubviewImplementationBlock, AnyObject.self))
method_setImplementation(originalDidAddSubviewMethod, newDidAddSubviewImplementation)
```

Now we can observe the notification and receive the corresponding event:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerWillOpen:", name: "PlayerWillOpen", object: nil)

func playerWillOpen(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("A Player will be opened now")
}
```

#### Better notification injection

Since the `AVPlayerView` won't get removed but only deallocated we'll have to rewrite our code a little bit and inject some notifications to the `AVPlayerViewController`. That way we'll have as many notifications as we want, e.g.: `PlayerWillAppear` and `PlayerWillDisappear`:

```
let originalViewWillAppearMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, "viewWillAppear:")
let originalViewWillAppearImplementation = method_getImplementation(originalViewWillAppearMethod)

typealias ViewWillAppearCFunction = @convention(c) (UIViewController, Selector, Bool) -> Void
let castedOriginalViewWillAppearImplementation = unsafeBitCast(originalViewWillAppearImplementation, ViewWillAppearCFunction.self)

let newViewWillAppearImplementationBlock: @convention(block) (UIViewController!, Bool) -> Void = { (viewController: UIViewController!, animated: Bool) -> Void in
    castedOriginalViewWillAppearImplementation(viewController, "viewWillAppear:", animated)

    if viewController is AVPlayerViewController {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PlayerWillAppear", object: nil)
    }
}

let newViewWillAppearImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(newViewWillAppearImplementationBlock, AnyObject.self))
method_setImplementation(originalViewWillAppearMethod, newViewWillAppearImplementation)

let originalViewWillDisappearMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, "viewWillDisappear:")
let originalViewWillDisappearImplementation = method_getImplementation(originalViewWillDisappearMethod)

typealias ViewWillDisappearCFunction = @convention(c) (UIViewController, Selector, Bool) -> Void
let castedOriginalViewWillDisappearImplementation = unsafeBitCast(originalViewWillDisappearImplementation, ViewWillDisappearCFunction.self)

let newViewWillDisappearImplementationBlock: @convention(block) (UIViewController!, Bool) -> Void = { (viewController: UIViewController!, animated: Bool) -> Void in
    castedOriginalViewWillDisappearImplementation(viewController, "viewWillDisappear:", animated)

    if viewController is AVPlayerViewController {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PlayerWillDisappear", object: nil)
    }
}

let newViewWillDisappearImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(newViewWillDisappearImplementationBlock, AnyObject.self))
method_setImplementation(originalViewWillDisappearMethod, newViewWillDisappearImplementation)
```

Now we can observe these two notifications and are good to go:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerWillAppear:", name: "PlayerWillAppear", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerWillDisappear:", name: "PlayerWillDisappear", object: nil)

func playerWillAppear(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("A Player will be opened now")
}

func playerWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("A Player will be closed now")
}
```

## URL of the video

I spent a couple of hours digging some iOS Runtime Headers to guess where I could find the URL pointing to the video, but I couldn't manage to find it. When I was digging into some source files of WebKit itself, I had to give up and accept that there's no *easy way* to do it, although I believe it's somewhere hidden and can be reached, but most likely only with a lot of effort.

Comment: I have this same need, but for os/x; sadly the notifications don't match?

Comment: @Fabio Poloni can i get video url with notification From WKWebView because some this type of application available in appstore.see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview please help me.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to add (inject) some user script to the `WKWebView`, this way is a little bit safer than method swizzling:

Here is related code:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()

if let jsSource = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("video_play_messenger", withExtension: "js"),
    let jsSourceString = try? String(contentsOfURL: jsSource) {
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jsSourceString, injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

    contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
    contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")
}

let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "URL_FOR_VIDEO")!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

For the controller of WKWebView, conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler` and implement this method:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "callbackHandler" {
        if let messageString = message.body as? String where messageString == "VideoIsPlaying" {
            // Vide is being played
        }
    }
}
```

Add `video_play_messenger.js` to your project:

```
function videoTags() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName("video");
}

function setupVideoPlayingHandler() {
    try {
        var videos = videoTags()
        for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            videos.item(i).onplaying = function() {
                webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("VideoIsPlaying");
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function setupVidePlayingListener() {
    // If we have video tags, setup onplaying handler
    if (videoTags().length > 0) {
        setupVideoPlayingHandler();
        return
    }

    // Otherwise, wait for 100ms and check again.
    setTimeout(setupVidePlayingListener, 100);
}

setupVidePlayingListener();
```

Reference: http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift

Answer (score 0):

I found a relatively simple solution using the `isPlayingAudio` property in `WKWebView`. This is working good in my testing so far, so feel free to try it out and find any edge cases where it fails.

1. Subclass `WKWebView`
2. Create new stored property `isPlayingVideo` and set default to `false`
3. Create computed property which figures out if a video is playing by evaluating JavaScript
4. Override `didChangeValue(forKey:)` method.
5. If changed key is `_isPlayingAudio`, check if both audio and video are playing and update stored property

```
class VideoObservingWebView: WKWebView { // 1
  var isPlayingVideo: Bool = false // 2
  
  var playsVideoSupportingPiP: Bool { // 3
    do {
      let jsResult = try evaluateJavaScriptSync("""
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('video'))
  .filter(video => video.readyState != 0)
  .length
""")
      guard let videosCount = jsResult as? Int else {
        return false
      }
      return videosCount > .zero
    } catch {
      return false
    }
  }
  
  override public func didChangeValue(forKey key: String) { // 4
    if key == "_isPlayingAudio" { // 5
      isPlayingVideo = isPlayingAudio && playsVideoSupportingPiP
    }
  }
```

This is the `evaluateJavaScriptSync` method I'm using in step #3.

```
extension WKWebView {
  func evaluateJavaScriptSync(_ javaScriptString: String, inFrame frame: WKFrameInfo? = nil) throws -> Any? {
    var result: Any? = nil
    var error: Error? = nil

    var waiting = true

    self.evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString, in: frame, in: .page) { r in
      switch r {
      case .success(let r): result = r
      case .failure(let e): error = e
      }
      waiting = false
    }

    while waiting {
      RunLoop.current.acceptInput(forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default, before: Date.distantFuture)
    }

    if let error = error {
      throw error
    }

    return result
  }
}
```