# wkwebview resize after window change notification

Tags: swift2, wkwebview

In swift, I have a audio/video url loaded but the view doesn't resize, IF, the url is to a local file; web URLs are fine.

I'd like to scale/grow/etc the view to track the window vs keeping to the original dimension. I went looking first to an IB to add a view constraint but no joy; the option wasn't enabled.

So I was thinking along the lines of this - a notification handler - ala objective-c, to resize when the window changes:

```
//  Listen for window resizes
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(WebViewController.windowResized(_:)), name: NSWindowDidEndLiveResizeNotification, object: nil)

var orig = CGSize(width: 0,height: 0)
func windowResized(urlObject : NSNotification) {
    let url = (self.webView.URL)
    if ((url?.isFileReferenceURL()) != nil) {
        let track0 = AVURLAsset(URL:url!, options:nil).tracks[0]
        if track0.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo
        {
            orig = track0.naturalSize
            print("original size ",orig)
            let bounds = webView.window?.contentView!.bounds
            webView.window?.setContentSize(orig)
            webView.bounds.size = orig
        }
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work as the new bounds setting doesn't work. Curious that notification NSWindowDidResizeNotification isn't available?

so maybe I'm going about this wrong.

So I'm asking if there's a better way to handle the size changing event to affect webView size or the plan.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView actually runs in a seperate window from your app. So getting notifications for your window will not work.

This post could hopefully lead you in the right direction to getting the right notifications

[How to detect a movie being played in a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996938/how-to-detect-a-movie-being-played-in-a-wkwebview/36996939#36996939)

Comment: My webView is an ivar to view controller added as a subview to the controller's view. This is osx, but I'm pretty sure there's not another window instance but thanks for the pointer. Along your lines though I did walk subviews, each allows magnification but still not getting it resized.

Answer (score 0):

So I altered my original to add 'webView.bounds.size = orig' then added the fix with viewLayout().

```
override func viewDidLayout() {
    super.viewDidLayout()

    let newSize = webView.bounds.size
    let aspect = orig.height / orig.width
    let magnify = newSize.width / orig.width
    let newHeight = newSize.width * aspect
    let adjSize = NSMakeSize(newSize.width-1,newHeight-1)

    webView.setMagnification(magnify, centeredAtPoint: NSMakePoint(adjSize.width/2.0, adjSize.height/2.0))
    view.bounds.size = adjSize
}
```

This however also magnifies the controls, and using other videos within the same webview causes layout skews; I'm getting closer but this fix has issues.

The rounding hack( h/w - 1) works whereas using round() and rint() didn't; I was trying to avoid scroll bars.  If there's a way to avoid having the webkit controls magnified, etc, let us know, thanks!